# How do I check which SSL Certificate my SIM800 module has by default using ATCommands? How do I enable to use HTTPS GET using ATCommands?

Tags: http, ssl, https, at-command

I want to get information from a particular web-page using HTTPS GET via GPRS connection using SIM800 Module connected to my Arduino Uno.
For using HTTPS, I read somewhere that I need to have the right SSL certificate. I wanted to know is there any way using which I can view the SSL certificate which is there by default in SIM800 Module using AT Commands?
Also, how do I enable it to use HTTPS GET, because I get ERROR message when I used AT+HTTPSSL and AT+CIPSSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use secured connection on arduino if you have GSM module which supports secured connections. Unlike the other answer said you CAN use arduino to make secured connections. These are the commands I use in SIM800 series module.

For https connection use  " AT+HTTPSSL=1  "

For secured  tcp connection use  " AT+CIPSSL=1 "

Comment: I get "ERROR" response when trying to use AT+CIPSSL=1 command with my SIM800C module, do you have any idea of possible reason for that?

Answer (score -1):

You should understand a fact that you cannot use https on arduino, i.e it doesn't support it. Thus you can use http instead of https it works same.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that. Is there any other microcontroller with which I can use my SIM800 module (apart from ARM) for HTTPS GET and POST

Comment: You can use http for requesting for webpage from your arduino.

Comment: I am using HTTP currently, but I was facing an issue when I was using some APIs with GET (like Google Maps API, SoundCloud, etc. ). These APIs had HTTPS, hence I asked this question

Comment: can you tell me what is the trouble that you face. I ask this because there is no option for using https on arduino, because of it small size

Comment: I was using this ATCommand:
AT+HTTPPARA="URL", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=38.908133,-77.047119&timestamp=1458000000&key=AIzaSyC092U_7y7tMbOaBQU466V3H2XaA5-m7R0
"
I am using Google Maps Time-zone retrieval API in it directly. Is this the right-way to use APIs with ATCommands to GET information from a web-page

Comment: You can most definitely use SSL on Arduino. I have a nano that successfully posts via HTTPS. And they do not work the same, HTTP is unsafe.